# Use American power tools in Philippines..?

Tags: electrical

My 1st post here Merry Christmas..!

Typhoon Odette damaged or destroyed most homes in my father-in-law's Cebu, Philippines neighborhood..!

They have no electrical power phone service etc...

I am planning to buy him a Honda EU22i 220vac generator and then send him 110vac American corded power tools... An Oregon 15amp chainsaw & a 12amp reciprocating sawzall...

Also send a 110vac 12ga 50ft extension cord and a 3000watt step down transformer ~ the Honda EU22i is 220vac 2,200 watts...

OK will an American GFCI pigtail between the tool & extension cord be safe and affective..?

Thanks for any advice,
George

Comment: Personally, I'd go with a battery powered tool setup.  It is far easier to find a battery charger that works with someone else's electricity than sets of tools that work with someone else's electricity.  20V batteries should be the minimum you consider, and the tools (which can reuse a few batteries) are rather cheap, often lightweight, and unencumbered by trying to get a power cord to them.

Comment: You're spending a lot of money and I think you can get a battery-based setup that will deliver more value/functionality for the money than the combination of things you have suggested.  Buy high voltage battery tools, buy lots of spare batteries, a big charging station and then you can buy a smaller generator that only has to charge batteries rather than powering big tools.

Comment: Honestly a gas chainsaw would be much better bang for your buck. You usually just have to mix in a small amount of oil to the fuel. A couple litres of fuel will go a long way.

Comment: Will change my plan to battery powered tools

Comment: If you are cutting down large trees or cutting up fallen trunks a gas chain saw is a good idea.   For small branch work you can use your sawzall.    A battery chain saw may have a role but I'm not sure.

Comment: jay I did learn from Google today that a chainsaw does not need extra amounts of watts to start ~ a 1200 watt chainsaw needs 1200 watts at startup SO that means a generator could power a corded chainsaw Amen

Answer (score 4):

Buying tools for people doesn't really work out. Shipping tools across oceans isn't a good plan. Especially not when the Philippines are involved, because of their weird power plugs.

> I am planning to buy him a Honda EU22i 220vac generator and then send him 110vac American corded power tools... An Oregon 15amp chainsaw & a 12amp reciprocating sawzall...

NO.  Don't do that.

### FAIL part 1: isolated and incompatible

(this applies to any 240V country) You don't want a situation where your few tools (and generator) are incompatible with every other tool and power source in the country.

They make perfectly respectable 240V tools, honest.  **Just buy those**.  Your father-in-law will know what to do with 240V appliances, believe me.  Buy a 240V generator and 240V tools, if you must. But see part 3.

Honestly.  People in the US think that all other countries are some sort of dysfunctional backwater, and that USA tools can save them. **Quality tools are available most everywhere**, it's just that most people don't want to pay for them. America is no different, witness the popularity of stores like Harbor Freight, Canadian Tire and the redoubtable Amazon Marketplace.

Note also that Europe and Australia and Asia market tools have twice as much power available to them - 3100 watts instead of 1500 watts.  That means for tools which need a lot of power, European tools are actually better.

Just don't buy them 120V tools. Really.

### FAIL part 2: Everything gets destroyed

(this is just the Philippines). You don't give any thought to socket keying, but it's done, and it works. It keeps you from plugging things into the wrong voltage.

However, that doesn't work in the Philippines. For some bizarre reason, their 240V socket *is exactly the same* as the North American 120V socket.   That means a US 120V tool in the Philippines will have a service life of nothin', as anyone will consider it perfectly reasonable to plug it into a 240V socket. Where it will be instantly destroyed.

Conversely, your generator will be viewed as broken, because it will fail to power any domestic tool plugged into it.

If you must buy them a tool, buy them a European, Australian, or Southeast Asian/Pacific Island tool.  They will change the plug to NEMA 1-15.

### Don't buy tools for others unless they ask

Trying to buy tools or computers to "help" other people is always a mistake.  Ask anyone who's ever tried to buy their parents a computer or tablet or phone. Tools are a very personal thing. They need to be selected by the person who will be using the tools. If they're not, then the person will not value the tools, and will usually not even use them.  What works for you doesn't necessarily work for them.

And this just creates family stress and resentment. It doesn't have the effect you want to. They're not going to be grateful.

Unless they ask for very specific tools, in which case, sure. But they will generally ask for tools found in their country.

### Beware taxes and duties

People buying foreign often get blind-sided by this.  The tools may be more expensive because of VAT or import duties charged on the items.  But you're going to get pinched by this anyway, by the Customs desk at the border - either via package inspection or luggage inspection. The duties and taxes to be paid to Customs will wipe out all the savings.

Mishandling this or trying to trick the tax-man could easily get you a refusal at immigration, and a future ban on entry.

Comment: Harper your answers are perfect, thanks; I finally came to the same conclusion today... Google taught me that no comnercial aircraft passenger or cargo are allowed to transport lithium batteries, especially to Alaska & Hawaii <--- Amazon, Aloha Air all say the same thing... Them battery powered (expensive) tools must be shipped in cargo containers on ocean going ships... Matson shipping only accepts full cargo containers which I am never gonna need or have funds to pay for... Then I would need to forward the shipping from Hawaii to the Philippines via an LBC box

Comment: You didn't mention that carriage on passenger aircraft was one of the requirements!

Comment: DO buy tools for your college-bound children no matter how much they do not appreciate them.  One night when they call you with a disembodied  doorknob in their hand and no clue what to do, you can tell them "Look in that blue plastic box I gave you.  There's a long thing with a plastic handle and a sort of a pointy cross shape at the other end. Pick it up ......"  and you can go from there.  :(

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the advice, here is my adjusted plan moving forward:

1. Shop for 20v battery powered tools that can use 220VAC for the charger, might eliminate need for transformer & extra extension cord
2. Per YouTube videos 220VAC power tools in the Philippines have insane high prices, still plan to send USA tools
3. The above changes would allow use of a smaller size generator, less expensive & dad's house is fine using one extension cord w/ power strip since all he needs is TV, a way to charge cell phone & power tool batteries.
4. I will try posting YouTube link for 900watt Ingco generator

Plan Update #2
Send money to dad once we can establish voice phone communication ~ let him buy the tools he wants in the Philippine stores near him ~ he asked for a chainsaw 2 years ago and the generator is something I want him to have especially now and for future typhoons ~ the battery powered tools was a great idea except air transport of lithium batteries is not allowed only cargo containers on ocean going ships of which require paying for a full cargo container ~ we will send him money not tools ~ Bless everyone here in helping us help the Philippines from typhoon Odette...
Happy Christmas ~ George
P.S. I need 14 more reputation points to score & credit your answers but the site noted my appreciation each time I clicked the up arrow at your answers...

Comment: Be sure to upvote answers that you found helpful, and mark the best/most helpful as the solution using the checkmark (you can mark your own answer as the solution). That is the way we say "thanks" here, instead of leaving "thanks" messages as answers or comments.

Comment: Not sure how to do that & can't figure out how to answer a 2nd time either ~ I can add comment to a persons answer tho. Will keep trying to learn ok

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with a 220V (or 240V) generator such as the one you listed:

- Voltage
- Frequency

Voltage can be easily handled with a transformer.

Frequency can **not** be so easily changed, and that can be a big issue for many motorized appliances, such as power tools.

A much better choice would be a 240V **60 Hz** generator with 120V and 240V output. You can use the 240V output for any 240V loads and 120V for the American power tools. For lighting, battery chargers, etc. the frequency generally won't matter and in some cases even the voltage won't matter - many things are now designed for as much as a 100V - 250V range. But frequency definitely matters for anything with an AC motor.

Comment: USA and Philippines both run at 60Hz, simplifying the problem on the frequency side.  However Philippines runs at 220V.  They are a little odd in the respect, as when you normally hear 220V, you think 50Hz.

Comment: Plan is changed to using battery powered tools & getting a cheaper smaller generator

Comment: " But frequency definitely matters for anything with an AC motor. "  No, not "definitely", it might matter or it might not.  There are "universal" motors that will run on any frequency of AC, and run on DC, they don't care.  I know older power tools would commonly use universal motors but that might not be true today.  Better magnets, cheaper electronics, and other advancements since might mean universal motors aren't common any more.  I'll agree it might not be wise to run tools on 50Hz if they list only 60Hz on the specs but there are motors that won't care.

Answer (score 0):

According to the internet, the Philippines typically runs 220V @ 60 Hz.

After you father-in-law fixes the damage with the tools, he'll want to run the generator to his home.  For this a 220V @ 60Hz generator would be ideal. There are three safe approaches:

- one "gen cord" to a home transfer switch
- one long "gen cord" running multiple devices
- multiple extension cords

If electricians are available, getting the home transfer switch installed is the easiest to live with; but, it requires his home being rewired at the panel.  Once installed, you basically shut off all the home circuits, switch the home from grid power to generator power, plug the gen cord from the generator into transfer switch, fire up the generator, and then turn on the critical circuit breakers taking care to not overload the generator.  Without a home transfer switch, no one should ever plug the generator into the home's wiring in any way, as without the home transfer switch, you will energize the power lines and possibly kill the line crew coming to repair the power grid.

If electricians are not available, then a single "gen cord", a specially rated power cord designed to take a 20 to 30 AMP generator output and provide one or more outlets suitable for appliances.  It may be a challenge to find one specific to the plug format your father-in-law needs.

The last option is to run multiple "normal" extension cords from the generator to the appliances, using one cord per appliance.  It is not recommended to use a splitter on a normal electrical cord, as the cords themselves can easily be overloaded, causing heat which causes failures and fires.

As far as your 12Ga power cord, odds are it's not enough to be considered a "gen cord", which are typically 10Ga.  It would make a very good single power cord.

For GFCI, many generators have GFCI outlets built-in unless they are designed to be coupled (two generators combined) to power homes.  If the multiple extension cord approach is being used, a "work site" generator should be selected, as it will minimally provide one "two socket" GFCI outlet.  For non-GFCI generators, there are plug-in GFCI adapters, where you insert the adapter between the device and the power cord.  With some shopping around, you might be able to find them in 220V @ 60Hz.

Most generators are not designed to run 24/7, and many have very short run times before they require maintenance (some as low as 100 hours before oil changes and 1000 hours before engine rebuilds).  Ensure that you check the models you are considering for continuous runtime limits and maintenance requirements.

To handle the tool requirements, I would opt for a 220V @ 60Hz battery charger, and a battery tool system.  A good example is Dewalt's 20V battery system.  This replaces the need for two power ratings, by simplifying the problem down to finding a battery charger.  For example, the Dewalt charger for 20V batteries using 220V @ 60 Hz is the "DeWalt DCB115".  With such a setup, you could then ship Dewalt reciprocating saws, radial saws, power drills, chainsaws, etc. without having to consider the power differences.  Once the power is in the battery, it doesn't matter what was used to charge it from the tool's point of view.

Comment: Dad lives in the country burns wood for cooking & no refrigerator ~ electricity needed for his TV and room fan

Comment: @zappit Well, if he can get an electrician, then he might want to install a "transfer switch" as being "in the country" power outages are more likely to take a long time to restore power.  Of course, electricians will be harder to find; but, once installed, he might even be able to power his whole home.  Until then, I'd go with a 220v generator and a 20v battery charger.  "Worksite generators" will have GFCI built-in, making the shopping easier.  They are typically used on construction sites, before power is available.  Charging (battery) tools with them should be a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about a chainsaw, get a gas powered chainsaw. The same amount of gas will cut a lot more wood if you put it in a chainsaw, than if you put it in a generator powering an electric chainsaw. Also... a chainsaw is a dangerous tool. It is much safer if you only have to think about the chainsaw, and not about the power cord getting tangled. Don't forget to ship some earmuffs with it (recommend 3M peltor), a spare chain, and sharpening file.

I like [this one](https://megavert.fr/machines/82161-ms-151-tc-e-rollo-e-mini-25cm-1-4-pm3-tronconneuse-stihl-elagage-0886661934676.html) because it is very small and light and can be used one-handed. If you need to cut large trees, that's not ideal, so YMMV.

Cordless power tools would be more useful and practical in this kind of emergency.

I don't know which brand is more popular in the Philippines, but since it is convenient to borrow and lend tools and batteries from neighbors, I'd suggest you check first or ask your friend. Perhaps it's Makita, since it's a Japanese brand.

Honestly, a sawzall isn't that useful when you have a chainsaw, unless you want to cut metal, and even then it's not that great. If you want to build, a circular saw is mort important. If your friends are doing demolition work on houses destroyed by a hurricane, they're more likely to need a crowbar, axe, and large hammer.

Also stuff like safety shoes, pants with knee pads, eye and ear protection, medkit, tough gloves, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful advice

Comment: I would send gift certificates which would work and tools can be purchased where need and compatible with the available power systems.